# Help on LM324 SUBCKT model

Tags: operational-amplifier, simulation, ngspice, eda, netlists

I'm newbie in ngspice and having a hard time to understand the LM324 models downloaded from various sources.

Made an example with 4 different instances to demonstrate my doubt.
The idealOpAmp works as supposed, but any instance of modeled LM324 (SN, ONSEMI, TI, etc) doesn't even get close.
The circuit is just an non-inverting amplifier with G=3, for 32Khz (so way below LM324 bandwith limits).
For convenience, cutted the relevant parts of the .libs (kept source refence inside), and annexed on the zip file with all parts.

In my understanding, the instances of circuits should give similar results .
On the following image, gwave vREFx3 shows the expected output (on ideal OpAMP), the others show different and strange results (different LM324 SUBCKT models).
Don't know what i am doing wrong.

- environment:
- Debian BookWorm-6.1.0-16-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.67-1 (2023-12-12) x86_64 GNU/Linux
- lepton-eda - 1.9.18
- ngspice - 42+ds-2~bpo12+1
- gwave 20190116-2+b2
- bash

Steps to reproduce:

```
 export SCHEMABASE=teste324_02
 lepton-netlist -g spice-sdb -O sort_mode -o ${SCHEMABASE}.net ${SCHEMABASE}.sch
 ngspice -b -r ${SCHEMABASE}.dat ${SCHEMABASE}.net
 gwave ${SCHEMABASE}.dat
```

Source schema:
[ZIP file with complete schematic and support files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S_p6NQvpbgfAAwNOViOlZFVIHN_2OdsF/view?usp=sharing)

Demonstration:
[image: gwaveView]

Circuit:
[image: Schematic Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triangles are a symptom of slew rate limiting. LM324 has a typical slew rate of 0.5 V/us. That's not fast enough to swing 30V in 16 us.

Flat sections are a symptom of limited output drive. LM324 has a typical positive drive of 30 mA, so it can only drive 9V into your 300 ohm load. Note that even with no load, it won't be able to drive 30V p-p with a 30V supply: see the "Output voltage swing" spec for the (somewhat complicated) details.

Typical limits are not guaranteed: different models and different batches of chips may have different behaviors.

Comment: Didn't recall slew-rate. Right on the spot. Changed output load to 3K ,. and it solved the issue. 
Don't have enough points to upvote your answer.  This one should be accepted.